# Merge folders with similar data structures and overwrite if same file name robocopy

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

Is it possible to merge 2 folders with similar data structures with robocopy? E.g. I have a large music database, I want to merge another folder into this database but keep all the files in the database the same, except if any files with the same name exist, overwrite them. A structure being like

```
C:\Music\Queen\
```

with files

```
C:\Music\Queen\We will rock you
C:\Music\Queen\Dont stop me now
```

And I want to merge a structure

```
D:\Music\Queen\
```

with files

```
D:\Music\Queen\Dont stop me now
D:\Music\Queen\Somebody to love
```

With the end result

```
C:\Music\Queen\We will rock you
C:\Music\Queen\Dont stop me now //overwritten! Important!
C:\Music\Queen\Somebody to love
```

I have tried

```
robocopy "C:\Music\" "D:\Music\" /E /XX /IS
```

But this doesn't overwrite files with the same name. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `/XX`.

**before**

```
 Directory of E:\scratch\music2\queen

12/14/2016  03:46 PM    <DIR>          .
12/14/2016  03:46 PM    <DIR>          ..
12/14/2016  03:41 PM               340 dontstopmenow.song
12/14/2016  03:41 PM               340 somebodytolove.song
               2 File(s)            680 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,980,783,489,024 bytes free
```

**Command** `robocopy music1 music2 /IS /E`

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Wednesday, December 14, 2016 4:12:27 PM
   Source : E:\scratch\music1\
     Dest : E:\scratch\music2\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /IS /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           0    E:\scratch\music1\
                           2    E:\scratch\music1\queen\
          *EXTRA File                 18        somebodytolove.song
100%        Older                     18        dontstopmenow.song
100%        New File                  18        wewillrockyou.song

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         2         0         2         0         0         0
   Files :         2         2         0         0         0         1
   Bytes :        36        36         0         0         0        18
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00


   Speed :                7200 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :               0.411 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : Wednesday, December 14, 2016 4:12:27 PM
```

**After**

```
 Directory of E:\scratch\music2\queen

12/14/2016  03:47 PM    <DIR>          .
12/14/2016  03:47 PM    <DIR>          ..
12/14/2016  03:41 PM               340 dontstopmenow.song
12/14/2016  03:41 PM               340 somebodytolove.song
12/14/2016  03:41 PM               340 wewillrockyou.song
               3 File(s)          1,020 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,980,783,489,024 bytes free
```

**file contents**

```
e:\scratch>type music2\queen\dontstopmenow.song
From music1 folder

e:\scratch>type music2\queen\wewillrockyou.song
From music1 folder

e:\scratch>type music2\queen\somebodytolove.song
From music2 folder
```